# Mini-profiler does not show any statistics on sql queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

The mini profiler does not show any statistics on sql queries

I do setup according to the documentation and the example of the application:
https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileEFCore
https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/main/samples/Samples.AspNetCore3/Startup.cs

here is my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql ("connstring..."));
    services.AddMiniProfiler()
        .AddEntityFramework();          
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiniProfiler();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                ...
            });
}
```

and an example of calling an sql query

```
            await using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>())
            {
                var myDatas = context.Datas.AsNoTracking()                    
                    .Where(x => x.StartTime > now );

                foreach (var myData in myDatas)
                {
                ...
                }
```

after executing this request I check the pages with the mini profiler statistics:

```
https://localhost:port/mini-profiler-resources/results-index
https://localhost:port/mini-profiler-resources/results?id=GUID
```

and see only this:

```
|                               | duration (ms)| with children (ms) | from start (ms)
| https://localhost:port/logins/| 231.9        | 236.5              | +0.0
| MiniProfiler Init             | 4.5          | 4.6                | +0.0
| Get Profiler IDs              | 0.1          | 0.1                | +4.5
```

**What did I miss ? Why can't I see statistics on SQL queries ?**

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. It was necessary to wrap calls to the database by referring to the mini profiler.

sample code from this article:
https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-miniprofiler-in-aspnetcore-webapi/

```
using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("PUT method"))
    {
        WeatherForecast weatherForecastById = null;
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Getting Weather Forecase for the Id"))
        {
            weatherForecastById = GetWeatherForecast(id);
        }

        if (weatherForecastById == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (weatherForecastById.Id != id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Updating the Data"))
        {
            _databaseContext.Entry(weatherForecast).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _databaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return NoContent();
    }
```